# How to stop simultaneous functions triggering/conflicting in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that makes use of the onEdit(e) trigger in Google App script. I need this trigger to launch when I update a certain part of my Excel sheet. This particular function takes around 30 seconds to complete and makes some modifications to the Sheet.

My problem is that if I make multiple edits to the relevant range, the sheet will launch 4-5 simultaneous instances of that function. They then conflict with each other causing incorrect results.

Is there a way to block simultaneous instances, or perhaps put a cooldown on the onEditfunction so that it won't launch until 30 seconds afterwards the first launch?

Answer (score 2):

### Put a [lock](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) on the contents of your `onEdit` function

- The lock service allows to protect the spreadsheet from changes through more than one script simultaneously.
- When one instance of the `onEdit` trigger is being fired - the first thing the function does is to try to acquire a lock.
- The script will obtain a lock, if no other script currently accesses the spreasheet.
- If the script cannot ubtain the lock straightaway, it will wait for the specified amount of time until the already running script finishes executing.
- If the script succeeds in obtaining a lock - no other script will obtain access to the spreadsheet until the lock is realesed.

Sample:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(20000);
  // DO SOMETHING
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: Do you recommend this for all functions with time based triggers or just OnEdits?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [Properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) to implement the "cooldown" by tracking the last edit timestamp

```
var editCooldownKey            = 'onEditCooldown';
var editCooldownInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000;
var currentTimestamp           = new Date().getTime();
var scriptProperties           = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var lastEditTimestamp          = scriptProperties.getProperty( editCooldownKey );

// If not set or have passed the cooldown, reset the cooldown. Otherwise, do not proceed
if ( lastEditTimestamp === null || currentTimestamp - lastEditTimestamp > editCooldownInMilliseconds ) {
    scriptProperties.setProperty( editCooldownKey, currentTimestamp );
} else {
    return;
}

// The rest of your logic goes here
```